# Forcing prepared requests from HTTPS back to HTTP Python Zeep client (wsdl https, binding needs to be http)

Tags: python, soap-client, zeep

Currently working on using zeep for a client binding to an application that we do not control (so we cannot change its behavior).

Unfortunately for me, the WSDL is hosted on a https:// page, while the binding itself ONLY support HTTP, so i cannot simply change the binding address to HTTPS to make this working.

When first creating the zeep client object I am assuming this is then a python requests prepared request, which now is forced to only accept SSL.

Question: Is there a way to tell zeep or python requests that the next response won't be HTTPS?

Example:

```
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

session = Session()
session.verify = False
transport = Transport(session=session)
client = Client('https://example.local:8443/www/core-service/services/LoginService?wsdl', transport=transport)

with client.settings(raw_response=True):
    print(client.service.login('0', 'user', 'password'))
```

This would return this error because the next call is towards an http address:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9090): Max retries exceeded with url: /core-service/services/LoginService (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:877)'),))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the "force_https" property to false in order to avoid the https forcing.

https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/settings.html#settings